# Troubleshooting ARIA [role] Relationships: Missing Required Children and Uncontained [role]s, Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, google-pagespeed

I'm working on my CEO and PageSpeed Insights are complaining about Some ARIA roles. It seems to be a problem with Bootstrap 5 and I don't manage to fix the problem. Any ideas on how to handle it?

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-rimord-no-nb/voaf80y0c2?hl=en&form_factor=mobile

The site:
https://www.rimord.no/nb/?q=bokse

I've looked a bit around to find ideas on how to fix it and even asked ChatGTP, but don't seem to find a solution.

Thanks.